# Determine characteristics for a PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Given the PDE $\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + 4 \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial x}= 0 $ determine the characteristics.

I understand how to solve this PDE using the method of characteristics as $\rho=f(x-4t)$, but I do not understand what is meant by "determine the characteristics".

Which equations are **the characteristics**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already solving the PDE with the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), than you're  computing the "characteristics"; the solution is a union of characteristic curves.

They are integral curves of a vector field which the solution is tangent to at every point. In other words, the solution is constant along them and the equation reduces to a ODE along the characteristic curves.

In your case, the curve $x(s), t(s)$ such that
$$
\dfrac{dx}{ds} = 4 \\
\dfrac{dt}{ds} = 1
$$